# I need to get the first log in database and determine if they're late. java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

Here's an example of my database

-table records

```
name    loginDate     loginTime  
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00  
Chris   2015-01-02    9:40  
Chin    2015-01-02    10:00  
Chris   2015-01-02    10:09  
Chin    2015-01-03    8:00  
Chin    2015-01-03    9:00  
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01  
Chris   2015-01-03    9:03
```

-table employee

```
name    startingTime  
Chin    8:30  
Chris   9:00
```

so basically, I need a query that can return only the first log-in in the day and determine if he's late by comparing the startingTime in another table. the return value should be:

```
Chin    2015-01-02    9:00  
Chris   2015-01-02    9:40  
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01
```

I use this code to determine the first login:

```
SELECT name, loginDate, MIN( loginTime )  
FROM   records  
GROUP BY name, loginDate
```

PS. I'm using java netbeans

If you can give me a query that can help me get the exact return value i need, thank you!

Comment: what is your desired outcome?

Comment: i already got the first logIn in a day. Now i need to check if he's late thru comparing them to the stated time in another table. I'm asking if there's a query that can give the output I need

Comment: why is there 9:40 for chris on jan 2nd? theres a 9:09?

Comment: my bad. let's just say it's 10:00

Comment: so do you want to just see the number of minutes they are late? or just text like LATE or ON TIME?

Comment: I need the desired output stated in the question, the 3 queries. But if also can make a new column with my desire output that tells me how many minutes they are late would be good. Thank you

Comment: Chin    2015-01-02    9:00  30 <br/>
Chris   2015-01-02    9:40  40 <br/>
Chris   2015-01-03    9:01  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want is the rows where the person is late then this should do what you want.

```
SELECT t.name, t.logindate, t.loginTime, if(timestampdiff(minute, t1.startingTime, t.loginTime) > 0, timestampdiff(minute, t1.startingTime, t.loginTime), 0) as is_late
FROM 
(   SELECT name, loginDate, TIME(MIN(loginTime)) as loginTime
    FROM records  
    GROUP BY name, loginDate
) t 
JOIN employee t1 ON t.name = t1.name
HAVING is_late > 0
```

the column is_late returns the number of minutes the person is late

maybe whatever you used is messing up with timestampdiff... try another format

```
SELECT t.name, t.logindate, t.loginTime, (TIME_TO_SEC(t.loginTime) - TIME_TO_SEC(t1.startingTime))/60 as is_late
FROM 
(   SELECT name, loginDate, MIN(loginTime) as loginTime
    FROM records  
    GROUP BY name, loginDate
) t 
JOIN employee t1 ON t.name = t1.name
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98ba01/4)

Comment: what would those be? @user2634806

Comment: It says that there is an error on either loginTime or timestamp.

Comment: are you for sure using mysql?

Comment: hmm, how are you executing the query? this is what I'm getting when i execute it. http://cl.ly/image/3r0G1y1W2I1e

Comment: @user2634806 i just edited with another query that does the exact same thing just uses a different function. try that one out

Comment: thank you for answering my question, it really helped me a lot! the query must be on a single line to execute, maybe because i'm using java netbeans. Thank you again!

Comment: @user2634806 oh ok, well then that makes sense. if you wouldn't mind accepting the answer i would greatly appreciate it :) i already gave you a +1 to counter act the -1 someone else gave you :)

Comment: i did use it hehe. just need to be in a single line hehe Thank you again!